# Generate delta tar for deployment from Grunt

Tags: powershell, deployment, gruntjs

Using Grunt (and Powershell if necessary) how can I build a tar file that contains all files modified since a specified date (recursive)?  I know some of the steps required to accomplish this, but not how to fit them together.

Using grunt-contrib-compress I am able to create a tar of **all** files:

```
compress: {
  full: {
    options: {
      archive: 'fullProject.tar'
    },
    files: [
      {
        src: ['**'],
        expand: true
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Using Powershell I can get a list of all files modified since a certain date:

```
dir -file -Recurse | ? {$_.LastWriteTimeUtc -gt ([datetime]"2015-04-01")}
```

Using grunt-shell I can run that Powershell script if necessary:

```
shell: {
    ps: {
      options: {
        stdout: true
      },
      command: 'powershell deltaBuild.ps1'
    }
  }
```

How can I build a tar file that contains all files modified since a specified date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking to do something similar, this was accomplished by writing a bash script that does the following:

1. Pipe the git log into file x.txt, e.g.: git log origin/master --name-status --after="2015-04-01T00:00:00" > x.txt
2. Run a perl script that reads x.txt, and outputs only the new/modified files into y.txt
3. Run a gulp task that reads each line of y.txt and copies that file into a temp directory
4. Run a gulp task that builds a tar of that temp directory